# Protect a directory in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I need your help to secure a repository. Un my website, I have the SonataAdminBundle + FOSUserBundle.

After loggin me on the sonata admin page (/admin), I want to get the connected user id in other page (/test).

My controller :

```
class CkeditorController extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    # How to get the user id ?

  }
}
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

`$this->getUser()->getId()`

which is a shortcut to

`$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();`

See the [Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object)

Comment: Thanks you, the problème was the firewall